# Create WebSockets between a TCP server and HTTP server in node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, tcpserver, httpserver

I have created a **TCP server** using ***Node.js*** which listens to clients connections.
I need to transmit data from ***TCP server*** to ***HTTP server*** again in Node.js possibly through a **Websocket** (*socket.io*).

However, I do not know how to create such connection such that TCP server is able to push data to HTTP server through Websocket.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You can use socket.io-client to connect HTTP server using socket.io

Comment: @nguyenkha : Can you please help me with the code sample please ?

Comment: Take the code from socket.io example http://socket.io/#how-to-use for client-side, only JavaScript part and `var io = require('socket.io-client');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was trying lot of things to get this work. Most of the time I was relying on **socket.io** to get this working, but it was just not working with TCP.

However, **net.Socket** suffices the purpose.

Here is the working example of it.

**TCP Server**

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 4040;

var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);

server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);
sock.write("TCP sending message : 1");
    console.log('Server listening on ' + server.address().address +':'+ 
        server.address().port);
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

**HTTP Server**

```
var http = require('http').createServer(httpHandler),
    fs = require("fs"),
    wsock = require('socket.io').listen(http),
    tcpsock = require('net');

var http_port = 8888;

var tcp_HOST = 'localhost';
var tcp_PORT = 4040;

/**
 * http server
 */
function httpHandler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

http.listen(http_port);
console.info("HTTP server listening on " + http_port);

wsock.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { 

    var tcpClient = new tcpsock.Socket();
    tcpClient.setEncoding("ascii");
    tcpClient.setKeepAlive(true);

    tcpClient.connect(tcp_PORT, tcp_HOST, function() {
        console.info('CONNECTED TO : ' + tcp_HOST + ':' + tcp_PORT);

        tcpClient.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('DATA: ' + data);
            socket.emit("httpServer", data);
        });

        tcpClient.on('end', function(data) {
            console.log('END DATA : ' + data);
        });
    });

    socket.on('tcp-manager', function(message) {
        console.log('"tcp" : ' + message);
        return;
    });

    socket.emit("httpServer", "Initial Data");
});
```

**Browser Client**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('httpServer', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    document.write(data + "\r\n");
    socket.emit('tcp', "For TCP");
  });
</script>
```

This way, there is a socket opened between HTTP server and TCP server in Node.js.

Comment: So 2 different servers?

Comment: @Ravis to send message from web client i tried to post a message to http server which end with Allow-origin-allow-origin error. Is it a correct way to post message from web client or i am doing any mistake? i have raised a question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32999794/4657065 . thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to communicate server-server than websockets is probably not a best choice. Try one of [RPC libraries](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-rpc), or just use HTTP or your own protocol.

Comment: Hey, Thanks @Andrey and  rdrey. Although I got the sockets working between a TCP and HTTP Server in Node.js. However, I would definitely try the RPC libraries in this case. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either socket.io or ws (only WebSocket) on Node.js as client (not only in browser)

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://IP address of Websocket server');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

Comment: I tried this. However, the problem is that it is not able to communicate with the TCP server created on Node.js. i.e. `var app = require('net').createServer(handle);` But it works when I change it to http.